# Running maximum of $\sum_{1\leq k\leq n} X_i$ for Cauchy random variables $X_i$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, extreme-value, cauchy-distribution, levy-distribution

Suppose $X_i$ are $\mathrm{Cauchy}(0,~\gamma)$ IID RV's and let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ be their sum. Does an expression exist for the CDF of the running maximum up to an index $1 \leq k \leq n$?

---

#### Edit:

[Darling 1956 (eq. 4.3)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1992908) obtain an expression for $\max{S_k}$ under a particular restriction on $X_i$. More recently, [Kznetsov, 2011](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.4208.pdf) has studied the supremum of strictly stable Lévy processes and [Boyarchenko and Levendorskiĭ, 2022](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02793.pdf) even go so far as to consider the computational efficiency of the numerical methods use to realize their results. I have, at the time of writing, only been able to skim the latter paper; if anyone has enough familiarity with the subject matter at hand to save me some time on this, please do note that all help is most welcome.

Comment: There is a well-known, exact expression for the distribution of the maximum value from a sample of size $n$ from any distribution; is that what you want?  It's a little unclear what you mean by "running extremum"...

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I meant it in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/298948) sense, but for Cauchy as opposed to a Wiener process. I figured that the symmetry of the distribution could then be exploited to obtain the extremum, as the maximum is equally as likely as the respective minimum

Comment: @jbowman I find the description clear, but if it helps, define $T_n = \max\{|S_i|\mid 1\le i\le n\}.$  The question asks for the cdf of $T_n.$ Note that this is the maximum of (very strongly) associated variables, so it's not evident what "well-known, exact expression" you might have in mind.

Comment: @whuber What do you mean by "associated" variables, in this sense? Also, I have heard of the work of Kac and Polland on $\max{|S_i|}$, but, because I cannot find the original paper anywhere, I do not have a sense of whether the one-sided maximum of the maximum of the absolute RV would be most convenient for establishing the overall running extremum. Could you please comment on that?

Comment: I have to use "associated" because these variables do not have a defined correlation.

Comment: It’s an interesting question, and difficult even asymptotically because a normal distribution can’t match the moments of the sums. Can you describe the context which led you to ask it?

Comment: @MattF. Why'd you change the question to the running extremum of the _absolute_ sum? Is that not a different matter entirely? I'm afraid to disappoint as to the context, which is mere happenstance; my curiosity got piqued by having seen a similar question pertaining to the one-sided maximum of Wiener processes

Comment: I've indeed edited it. I hope it's clear now

Comment: @MattF. I've changed the title again. I think you're indeed correct that the analysis of the running minimum is analogous and that the previous formulation was too confusing